# What's the best way to log in Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

Just want some insight on this.

Currently I'm using console log in an Angular SPA. but obviously this log is only viewable when I develop it. When it is out there in other people's browse, I have no way to see and check.

What library/tools I can use to have this sort of runtime information when the SPA is in beta test, or even in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using AngularJS, your best option is to use the [$log](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log) service  (which you have to inject into your own controllers, etc.)

Then, there are a few options to get the relevant bits out:

- [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) - mostly focused on error/warning reporting, is [integrated](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/javascript/integrations/angular/) with AngularJS - good for production
- [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/docs/angular-js-logs/) - collects everything, good for staging environments
- [Build your own](http://engineering.talis.com/articles/client-side-error-logging/) - if you are feeling brave!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look a services like:

- https://trackjs.com/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/services/application-insights/
- https://raygun.io/

and others like them, and see what you think fits your scenario best.